# Win7's "restore down" by dragging window title bar... in XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

In Windows 7 you can drag the title bar of a window that has been maximized and the window will "restore down" and let you drag it. Is this behavior possible in XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might also check out Stardock's [WindowFX](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowfx/).

Comment: Wow, this looks great! Works like I want and has more features like the Win7 shake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a program similar to this called AeroSnap.  It's in BETA but it's free and very useful in Windows XP.

http://www.aerosnap.de.vu/

AeroSnap is a simple but powerful application that allows you to resize, arrange or maximize your desktop windows with just drag'n'drop.

Simple drag a window to a side of your desktop to snap it or drag it to the top to maximize.

When you drag it back to the last position, the last window size will be restored. Really easy, isn't it?

It also works with multiple monitors!

Download available here.

http://aerosnap.de/download/aerosnap/current_version/aerosnap_0_61_setup.exe

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do what I want. Unfortunately I don't really like the way it does it. I guess the answer here is that it is possible _if_ I want to write the app that does it.

Comment: aerosnap seems to have gone now